# Comparing a class to None

Tags: python

I have a supposedly simple situation where I am trying to sort a list that contains a mix of class instances, and None. I've implemented the **lt** method of the class, but I'm still getting an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'test_class
```

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
class test_class:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        else:
            return self.num < other.num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        else:
            return self.num == other.num

tc1 = test_class(1)
tc2 = test_class(2)

sorted([tc1, tc2, None])
```

... which produces the above-mentioned error. Could anyone kindly point out what I'm doing wrong? In some sort of idealized reality where programming languages work in a common-sense way, I would have thought that the 'if other is None' bit should handle a comparison with None.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error happens when None is in the left-hand side of the comparison.

Comment: Aha. That actually does make some sense. Is there any way to get around it, though?

Comment: Make a lambda function to work as a key: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411610/10953328).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your error is not

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'test_class' and 'NoneType'
```

but instead

```
...between instances of 'NoneType' and 'test_class'
```

The ordering matters. `None` does not implement a `__lt__` method that knows how to compare to a `test_class`. However Python is smart enough to use the other class's `__gt__` in this case.

```py
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        else:
            return self.num < other.num

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return True
        return self.num > other.num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        else:
            return self.num == other.num
```

What's more, [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) can be used to decorate your class so you only have to define `__eq__` and one of `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__` and the rest will be auto generated for you.

```py
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other is None: return False
        return self.num < other.num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.num == other.num
        # I refactored this to be a little nicer
```

Now `TestClass()` acts as if `__gt__`, `__ge__`, and `__le__` are all defined, even though you only have to define one.

Comment: thanks - this is very helpful. I was unaware of functools.total_ordering but I can see myself using it plenty in future.