# How can I sort a python list that includes strings and None?

Tags: python

In python,

```py
sorted(["a", "b", None])
```

produces

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-2c38da1a26e5> in <module>
----> 1 sorted(["a", "b", None])

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I can write something hacky like

```py
def sort_with_none(my_lst):
    if None not in my_lst:
        result = sorted(my_lst)
    else:
        result = (
            sorted([xx for xx in my_lst if xx is not None])
            + [xx for xx in my_lst if xx is None]
        )
    return result
```

And then calling

```py
sort_with_none(["a", "b", None])
```

works fine.  But I assume there's a slicker way to do this.  Any advice?

Comment: Hmm, looks like this question basically answers mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411560/python-sort-list-with-none-at-the-end

Answer (score 1):

simple solution is use [key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) option

```
sorted(["a", "b", None], key=lambda x: x or '')
```