# How to sort dict by value, provided that the value contains both int and None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the dict

```
d = {a: (None,), 'b': (None,), 'c 9:00': (32400,), 'd 10:23': (37380,)}
```

I need to get

```
{'c 9:00': (32400,), 'd 10:23': (37380,), a: (None,), 'b': (None,)}
```

How?

Comment: What was wrong with the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value, possibly combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411560/sort-list-while-pushing-none-values-to-the-end?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert None values to some lager value (+ infinity) and then try to sort them, like

```
import math
for k,v in d.items():
    if v[0] == None:
        d[k[0]] = (math.inf,)
```

Now sorting by value

```
d_sorted = dict(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]))
```

output

> `{'c 9:00': (32400,), 'd 10:23': (37380,), 'a': (inf,), 'b': (inf,)}`